# Not able to set the text via setText function in Android

Tags: android

I want to set a value by using setText function. But my code is not working.

**activity_my.xml**

```
    <Button
    style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.ActionBar.TabBar"
    android:theme="@android:style/Animation.Activity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Select"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:textColorHighlight="#ffff7dd0"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ff1fff5f"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="129dp"
    android:onClick="BookChapter"/>@
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {   
    @Override    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);   
  }

  public void BookChapter(View view){
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_secbg);    
  } 
}
```

**activity_secbg.xml**

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Chapter 01"
    android:id="@+id/button01"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="BookContent"/>
```

**show_content.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Existing Text"`
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:editable="true" />
```

**show_content.java**

```
public class Show_Content extends Activity {
    public TextView myAwesomeTextView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    } 

    public void BookContent(View view) {
      setContentView(R.layout.show_content);
      switch (view.getId()) {
        case (R.id.button01):
        myAwesomeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(textView5);
        myAwesomeTextView.setText("Awesome");
        break;
      }
     }
   }
```

Could anybody please help to check why the setText is not working for this program?

Comment: Please, format your code using proper markdown

Comment: Please be more specific - which field? Also please format your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a method in a java from another java.. the method returning the text is in `show_content` class.

you are calling the method in the `MyActivity` class.

So the `BookChapter` method you are using, is not the one setting the text, it simply call the `setContentview` method. Plus you are missing the `setContentView` method in the second activity

You have two activities but only a method fired, or you are missing a lot of code in the lines you wrote, or you have to start studying how android works before programming, I suggest you [those videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QAbQgLGKd3Y). in my opinion they are the best for beginners

Good luck

Comment: public void BookContent(View view) {
      setContentView(R.layout.show_content);
      switch (view.getId()) {
        case (R.id.button01):
        myAwesomeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(textView5);
        myAwesomeTextView.setText("Awesome");
        break;
      }
     }

Comment: I need to put the BookContent() code in MyActive.java file, seems like it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

in your `Show_Content`  activity's `onCreate` add this line

```
 setContentView(R.layout.show_content);
```

it Should be:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.show_content); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not getting any View from your Activity. Also, you forgot to set the layout in your Activity.

```
    public TextView myAwesomeTextView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.show_content);
        myAwesomeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        myAwesomeTextView.setText("Awesome");

    }
```